# Django query group by month and year

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have a Django model like this:

```
class EVENT(models.Model):
    user = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    pay_time = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

I need to calculate the average number of records per month I have for a certain group of users. I have the user names in a list and I want to group by month and year to use in the average calculation. My query is like this:

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import Func, F, Count
class Month(Func):
    function = 'EXTRACT'
    template = '%(function)s(MONTH from %(expressions)s)'
    output_field = models.IntegerField()

class Year(Func):
    function = 'EXTRACT'
    template = '%(function)s(YEAR from %(expressions)s)'
    output_field = models.IntegerField()

#ru is the list of usernames I want to get the average per month for
trx = EVENT.objects.filter(user__in=ru).annotate(m=Month('pay_time'), y=Year('pay_time')).values('m', 'y').annotate(c=Count('id'))
```

When I run this query I get the results I thought I wanted. That's a sample of what I got:

```
<QuerySet [{'y': 2016, 'c': 61098, 'm': 4}, {'y': 2016, 'c': 104632, 'm': 5}]>
```

I wanted to make sure so I ran this query:

```
trx2 = EVENT.objects.filter(user__in=ru, pay_time__year=2016, pay_time__month=4)
```

And I got the result 60990 records.
This means that the results I got from the first query are incorrect. I know I can use the second query in a loop to get what I want but this will be very slow compared to running one query using GROUP BY.

Thanks,

EDIT:
Here is the output of `print trx.query`:

```
SELECT 
    EXTRACT(YEAR from `events_event`.`pay_time`) AS `y`,  
    EXTRACT(MONTH from `events_event`.`pay_time`) AS `m`,
    COUNT(`events_event`.`id`) AS `c`
FROM `events_event`
WHERE  
 `events_event`.`user` IN ('user1', 'user2')
GROUP BY 
  EXTRACT(YEAR from `events_event`.`pay_time`),
  EXTRACT(MONTH from `events_event`.`pay_time`)  
ORDER BY NULL
```

And this is the output of `print trx2.query`:

```
SELECT
    `events_event`.`id`,
    `events_event`.`user`,
    `events_event`.`pay_time`,
FROM `events_event`
WHERE
    (`events_event`.`user` IN ('user1', 'user2')
 AND `events_event`.`pay_time` BETWEEN 2015-12-31 22:00:00 AND 2016-12-31 21:59:59.999999 
 AND EXTRACT(MONTH FROM CONVERT_TZ(`events_event`.`pay_time`, 'UTC', Africa/Cairo)) = 4)
```

Comment: does your model has `ordering` try add empty `order_by` to your first query

Comment: tried adding `.order_by()` at the end and got the same results. @BearBrown

Comment: can you add result of `print trx.query` and `print trx2.query` to your question, please.

Comment: @BearBrown done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think the solution here, in the `CONVERT_TZ`

```
EXTRACT(MONTH FROM CONVERT_TZ(`events_event`.`pay_time`, 'UTC', Africa/Cairo))
```

you can try

```
class Month(Func):
    function = 'EXTRACT'
    template = "%(function)s(MONTH from CONVERT_TZ(%(expressions)s, 'UTC', 'Africa/Cairo'))"
    output_field = models.IntegerField()
```

Comment: Great this solved the problem. I didn't think to look at the queries.

Comment: glad to help you, and i think better use timezone as variable